# Is this procedure to read and update a module level array variable "thread-safe"?

Tags: javascript

Recently, someone raised question about the following function I wrote. They think it is not "thread-safe" and thus, may create race condition and end up with results which inconsistent and unpredictable...

```
const activeModalErrorMessages: string[] = []

export const showModalErrorMessages (title: string, message: string)
{
   const activeErrorCheck = `${title}-${message}`;
   // filter out repeating error message modal that is still open on screen
  if (!activeModalErrorMessages.includes(activeErrorCheck)) {
    activeModalErrorMessages.push(activeErrorCheck);
    notification.error({
      message: title,
      description: message,
      duration: 0,
      onClose: () => {
        activeModalErrorMessages = activeModalErrorMessages.filter(
          item => item !== activeErrorCheck,
        );
      },
    });
  }
}
```

As I know, javascript is single-threaded. So I cannot see how two calls to the above function can happen to take place at the same time and create a "race condition". Am I right or wrong?!

Comment: javascript is normally single threaded (but with web workers you can have many threads that can even share memory) but can run code asynchronously. So as long as you don't use web workers, your code is thread-safe, but if you use asynchronous elements, there can be race conditions.

Comment: The `onClose` function runs asynchronously from the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1):

While JavaScript is indeed single-threaded, it is also asynchronous. This means that functions can be called without blocking the thread and as a result, a race condition can happen. Here is what it looks like:

```js
setTimeout(() => console.log('Expect Fifth'), 5);
setTimeout(() => console.log('Expect Second'), 1); // Got First
setTimeout(() => console.log('Expect Fourth'), 3);
setTimeout(() => console.log('Expect First'), 0); // Got Second
setTimeout(() => console.log('Expect Third'), 2);
```

Comment: `
let t = [];

async function pusher() {
if (!t.includes('world')) t.push('world');
}


let promises = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  promises.push(pusher());
}

Promise.all(promises).then(() => console.log(t))  // ['world']
`

Just one 'world' in the array. Doesn't that mean there is no race condition when the promises resolve?